# Console App...Objects of a Class

Tags: c#

I have created 2 classes. One class has instance variables, default constructor, constructor with parameters, properties and one function/method. the second class, contains my main method and is required to read data from a txt. file and then save the data to the 3 different objects.

I created 3 objects that look like this
NewEmployee employee1 = new NewEmployee();

this is what my code looks like to read the text file

```
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users/path))
    {

    while((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

How do I save the data from the text file to each object?
This is what the text file looks like:
First Name
Last Name
IdNUm
Start Year
Initial Salary
repeats 2x

Comment: how are they delimited? By space? Tab? And each person is on each row?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what the OP wants:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filepath"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] split = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
        employees.Add(new Employee
        {
            FirstName = split[0],
            LastName = split[1],
            EmployeedID = Int32.Parse(split[2]),
            StartYear = Int32.Parse(split[3]),
            InitialSalary = Decimal.Parse(split[4])
        });
    }
}
```

This assumes the lines are delimited by space and that the values will cast into the proper types. You can add the error handling but this will get you started.